# Iterate through "dropdown" elements when user presses a key

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, dropdown

I'm using Angular 6 and I'm having trouble with a dropdown.

When a the dropdown is focused and a user presses a key 'I' for example it selects the first option that starts with that letter (in this case it selects Idaho from an array containing states), when the user presses 'I' again it should select the next element on the list starting with an 'I' (Illinois), but it stays in the same element.

I'm using [this dropdown select module](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) and I implemented it to my html with this tag:

```
<ng-select [items]="this.stateNames" [(ngModel)]="shippingInfo.shippingAddress.state" #state="ngModel" name="state" required placeholder="Select State" bindLabel='long' bindValue='short' placeholder="Select a State"[searchable]="false" [clearable]="false"></ng-select>
```

I tried to iterate programmatically using the `keypress` and `change`
 events adding

```
(change)="this.stateChange($event, shippingInfo.shippingAddress.state)" (keypress)="this.keypressEvent($event, shippingInfo.shippingAddress.state)"
```

to the `ng-select` tag. The handler functions look like this:

```
currentKey = '';
stateIndex = 0;

keypressEvent(e, currentState) {
  console.log('\n\nK E Y   P R E S S');
  console.log('key pressed: ', e.key);
  if (e.key === this.currentKey.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log('same key');
    this.stateIndex++;
  }
  console.log('currentState: ',currentState);
  const currentIndex = this.stateNames.findIndex((element)=>{
    return element.short === currentState
  });
  if (this.stateNames.length > this.stateIndex) {
    if (this.stateNames[this.stateIndex].long[0].toLowerCase() === e.key) {
      this.shippingInfo.shippingAddress.state = this.stateNames[this.stateIndex].short;
      console.log('new state: ', this.shippingInfo.shippingAddress.state);
    }
  }
}

stateChange(e, currentState) {
  console.log('\n\nS T A T E   C H A N G E');
  this.currentKey = currentState[0];
  console.log('currentState: ', currentState);
  console.log('key stored: ', this.currentKey);
  this.stateIndex = this.stateNames.findIndex(x =>  x.short === currentState);
  console.log('State index: ', this.stateIndex);
  console.log('actual value: ', this.shippingInfo.shippingAddress.state);
}
```

I noticed some curious/weird behavior:

- When I press the same key multiple times quickly `stateChange` won't trigger and the selected item changes as expected but when I stop and then press the same key again it will go to the first state starting with that letter.
- When I press the same key ('I' for example): the first time it selects Idaho as expected, and the second time `keypress` triggers briefly selecting Illinois (this is what I want) but then `stateChange` also triggers and sets it back to Idaho.

this.stateNames is an array containing objects with the names of the states, like this:

```
[
{ "short": "AL", "long": "Alabama"  },
{ "short": "AK", "long": "Alaska"  },
{ "short": "AZ", "long": "Arizona" },
{ "short": "AR", "long": "Arkansas" },
{ "short": "CA", "long": "California" },
{ "short": "CO", "long": "Colorado" },
{ "short": "CT", "long": "Connecticut" },
{ "short": "DE", "long": "Delaware" },
{ "short": "DC", "long": "District Of Columbia" },
{ "short": "FL", "long": "Florida" },
{ "short": "GA", "long": "Georgia" },
{ "short": "HI", "long": "Hawaii" },
{ "short": "ID", "long": "Idaho" },
{ "short": "IL", "long": "Illinois" },
{ "short": "IN", "long": "Indiana" },
{ "short": "IA", "long": "Iowa" },
{ "short": "KS", "long": "Kansas" },
{ "short": "KY", "long": "Kentucky" },
{ "short": "LA", "long": "Louisiana" },
{ "short": "ME", "long": "Maine" },
{ "short": "MD", "long": "Maryland" },
{ "short": "MA", "long": "Massachusetts" },
{ "short": "MI", "long": "Michigan" },
{ "short": "MN", "long": "Minnesota" },
{ "short": "MS", "long": "Mississippi" },
{ "short": "MO", "long": "Missouri" },
{ "short": "MT", "long": "Montana" },
{ "short": "NE", "long": "Nebraska" },
{ "short": "NV", "long": "Nevada" },
{ "short": "NH", "long": "New Hampshire" },
{ "short": "NJ", "long": "New Jersey" },
{ "short": "NM", "long": "New Mexico" },
{ "short": "NY", "long": "New York" },
{ "short": "NC", "long": "North Carolina" },
{ "short": "ND", "long": "North Dakota" },
{ "short": "OH", "long": "Ohio" },
{ "short": "OK", "long": "Oklahoma" },
{ "short": "OR", "long": "Oregon" },
{ "short": "PA", "long": "Pennsylvania" },
{ "short": "RI", "long": "Rhode Island" },
{ "short": "SC", "long": "South Carolina" },
{ "short": "SD", "long": "South Dakota" },
{ "short": "TN", "long": "Tennessee" },
{ "short": "TX", "long": "Texas" },
{ "short": "UT", "long": "Utah" },
{ "short": "VT", "long": "Vermont" },
{ "short": "VA", "long": "Virginia" },
{ "short": "WA", "long": "Washington" },
{ "short": "WV", "long": "West Virginia" },
{ "short": "WI", "long": "Wisconsin" },
{ "short": "WY", "long": "Wyoming" }
]
```

Comment: why don't you are making it editable?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Just a side-note: Since you're running Angular 5 version, did you install 'ng-select' version 1.x? See versions description [here](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I made a mistake, I'm using Angular 6, and ng-select version 2.3.3